# Unable to use a component as a plugin when it has its own vuex store setup

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I have a component thats more like an app with its own vuex store. I need to wrap this up as a plugin and then use inside another app where there will be a main store. I tried doing it but no success. Below are the things I did...

To wrap it, I defined a file called bundle.js wherein I have set the following code. I will be using this file as a target for building.

```
import Scheduler from './App.vue';
import store from './storeBuild';

export default {
    install(Vue, options) {
        if (!options || !options.store) {
            throw new Error('Please initialise plugin with a Vuex store.')
        }

        options.store.registerModule('schedulerLib', store)

        Vue.component('scheduler', Scheduler)
    }
}
```

Here is the package.json where I have the build script

```
{
  "name": "scheduler",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "main": "dist/scheduler.common.js",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "build-bundle": "vue-cli-service build --target lib --inline-vue --name scheduler ./src/bundle.js" // The script to build the bundle
  },
"dependencies": {
  ..........
 }
}
```

and my store file will directly export the object instead of creating a store

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default {
    namespace: true,
    state: {
     layout: 'main-layout',
     nestedObject: {},
    },
    mutations: {
     // Has more than 20 handlers
    },
    actions: {

    },
    modules: {
    }
}
```

After running the build-bundle I had the code along with my dist folder push into the git.
Then I add it as a package in my other app using the gitlab link
(ie) yarn add git+https://abc:sdbfkn45234ADFGDF@gitlab.com/abc/task-scheduler.git#master // here task-scheduler is the repo name

I was able to solve the early stage barrier and now Iam able to see the store setup of the library but still I am not able to see the UI of the libary inside my layout.
Note that the layout that I have inside the plugin itself is dependent on one the state variables so the plugins store is not integrated properly then layout wont show up.

Below is the App.vue file of the plugin

```
<template>
  <div id="scheduler">
    <component v-bind:is="layout"></component>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from "vuex";
import MainnLayout from "./components/layouts/MainnLayout";
import WbsLayout from "./components/layouts/WbsLayout";
import "@/components/global";

export default {
  name: "scheduler",
  computed: {
    ...mapState(["scheduleLayout"]),
    layout() {
      return this.scheduleLayout;
    },
  },
  components: {
    "mainn-layout": MainnLayout,
    "wbs-layout": WbsLayout,
  },
};
</script>

<style lang="scss">
#scheduler {
  font-family: Lato, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  min-width: 940px;
}
</style>
```

I have added the screenshots below for reference
[image]
[image]

As suggested by @Dan,I updated the change in the plugin component and was able to bring up the module in the parent app
and my vuex in the parent app now shows the module but still I have errors on my console
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hey Ama. That unexpected token error needs to be taken care of first.  Then add a "d" to `namespaced`, and call `mapState` like `...mapState('schedulerLib', ['scheduleLayout']),` with the module name argument first.

Comment: Ok I will resolve that error and add that 'd' as well...

Comment: the mapState change...do you want me to do it inside the plugin or the app where iam trying to use the plugin?

Comment: Ok I ll do it in the parent app since I understood why you are asking me to do so...but why in the plugin app...I dont get it

Comment: Yeah unless I'm misunderstanding what you're doing.  The parent will use the Scheduler component, and when that component goes to the store, it will be the parent's store where the plugin object has become a Vuex module

Comment: I get that .. updating the change in the parent app makes sense

Comment: I ll try it and let you know

Comment: @Dan Please check the update in the question

Comment: Some problem with `taskCode`'s parent, but we don't see where you used it